# In Altium Designer, is there a setting that maintains the camera's position when switching from 2D to 3D and vice versa?

Tags: altium

When I switch from 2D to 3D mode, Altium zooms to the spot on the board I was viewing the last time I was in 3D mode.

**The behavior I would like:** When I switch from 2D mode to 3D mode, I see *same* part of the board that I was looking right before switching from 2D to 3D (and vice versa).

Is there a setting that does this?

Comment: I would also like to know this as well. I never really thought about the possibility of being able to change that, but now that you mentioned it, I really want to be able to do this.

Comment: For such a tool-specific question, the tool's own support website and/or user forum is usually your best bet. There is really no electronics design content in this question.

Answer (score 15):

The standard keys to use to switch to a given view are:

- 2D:  <kbd>2</kbd>
- 3D  <kbd>3</kbd>

If you add  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>  +  <kbd>ALT</kbd>  to these, the camera will retain your current view after the switch takes place:

- 3D to 2D:  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>Alt</kbd>  +  <kbd>2</kbd>
- 2D to 3D:  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>Alt</kbd>  +  <kbd>3</kbd>

These commands aren't overtly well documented. I came across them by chance a few months ago here: [Altium Documentation](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/pcb-cmd-switchto2dswitchto2d-ad)